# Matlab - How do I plot my data?

Tags: matlab, csv, plot, data-visualization

I have a number of CSV files, each one represents a 3D surface plot that I wish to generate.

The file's structure is as follows:

- The column numbers of the file represent the X-axes
- The the values in each row represent the Y-axes
- and the row number represents the Z-axes

**However**, every-other line in the file represents the the previous line's data points, +1 standard deviation.

Also, each pair of rows is longer than the last one.

So what I would like is two surfaces on each plot. The first surface being represented by every odd-numbered line, and the second one represented by every even-numbered line.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That I know of you can't have a non-square matrix in Matlab. So the closest you
can do is put NaNs in the spaces that are missing:

```
A = [
    10 10 NaN NaN NaN
     2  2 NaN NaN NaN
    20 20 20 NaN NaN
     3  3  3 NaN NaN
    30 30 30 30 30
     4  4  4  4  4
];
```

Everything else is the same.

Split:

```
[rows, cols] = size(A);
A_mean = A(1:2:rows, :);
A_sd   = A(2:2:rows, :);
```

Make axes (I rearranged these to be like yours ;)

```
[XX, ZZ] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:(rows/2))
```

And plot:

```
surf(XX, A_mean, ZZ); hold('on');
surf(XX, A_sd, ZZ); hold('off')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I omitted an important piece of information from my question that I've now added: Each pair of rows is longer than the previous pair. Also could you tell me what the order of your x,y,z is so I can figure out what to change to have it how I want? Thanks.

Comment: If it isn't possible without filling the ends of the rows up with zeros I don't mind - but I also would require some guidance in how to do that - thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Griffin I don't remember what happens if you read in a non-square CSV -- I think it will put 0s where there are no cells. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @Owen, you *can* read CSV files with m columns and n rows when m is not equal to n. This is a non-issue.

Comment: @ephsmith Sorry I meant non-rectangular ;)

Comment: @Owen, I had to transform my data files with a bit of C to get rectangular CSV files. I had to swap around the axes but it's ok now. Thanks.